# Is it good to have abbreviated tags right from the beginning?

Tags: discussion

There might be tags which get in conflict with each other because they are abbreviated. E.g. [wp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp) could be about `Windows Phone` or `Wordpress`. [fdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdt) could be about `Flash Development Tools` or `Field Device Technology`.  On the other hand side we have tags like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) but not [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js).

I don't worry about abbreviated tags which are clearly dominating the market. But how about tags which are not used frequently and where it's not possible to decide yet which one will be more popular in the future? Is it ok to use the abbreviated form from the beginning (tag creation) or should we use the long form first and add a tag synonym later when it's clear who is the winner?

Comment: I must say I use 'SCCM' more often than I use 'System Center Configuration Manager' while I'm searching for help topics, same with JS. But I wouldn't abbreviate thing like Windows Phone etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Always use the full name whenever possible. Not only are abbreviations ambiguous, but also confusing to users whom are newer in the topic or just not familiar with it.

Our best course of action is to be detailed from the get-go so we don't have to worry about *any* disambiguation issues in the future. We already have enough of those.

Answer (score 9):

It is always better to avoid acronyms and/or abbreviations since they might be confusing.

The only exception I might understand is when a concept or a technology is way better known with the acronym rather than with the full name (e.g. UML, HTML, these might even be unknown to a newbie when "expanded" to their full names)